# Handling nested schema in fast api while storing data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, python-3.10

I have a nested schema in fast api below is the book model`

```
class Book(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(256), index=True)
    subtitle = Column(String(256), index=True)
    narrator = Column(String(128), index=True)
    publisher_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("publisher.id"))
    publishers = relationship("Publisher", back_populates="books")
    length = Column(Integer, index=True)  # length in minutes
    release_date = Column(Date, index=True)
    language = Column(String(32), index=True)
    rating = Column(Float, index=True)
    description = Column(ARRAY(String(1024)), index=True)
    cover_image = Column(String(256), index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="books")
```

That has a related to publisher model as below `

```
class Publisher(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    books = relationship("Book", back_populates="publishers")
```

and their respective schema as below

```
class BookBase(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = Field(..., title="Book title", example="Atomic Habits")
    subtitle: Optional[str] = Field(
        None,
        title="Book subtitle",
        example="An Easy & Proven Way to Build Good Habits & Break Bad Ones",
    )
    narrator: Optional[str] = Field(..., title="Narrator", example="James Clear")
    # publisher_id: Optional[int] = Field(None, title="Publisher ID")
    publisher: Optional[PublisherBase] = Field(None, title="Publisher")
    length: Optional[int] = Field(..., title="Length", example=335)
    release_date: Optional[datetime.date] = Field(..., title="Release Date")
    language: Optional[str] = Field(..., title="Language", example="English")
    rating: Optional[float] = Field(..., title="Rating", example=4.8)
    description: Optional[list] = Field(..., title="Description")
    cover_image: Optional[HttpUrl] = Field(
        ...,
        title="Book Cover Image",
        example="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/513Y5o-DYtL._SL500_.jpg",
    )

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

and publisher schema

```
class PublisherBase(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = Field(..., title="Publisher name", example="Penguin Audio")

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

based on the relationship above i have the below crud method that accepts book item with a nested publisher `

```
class CRUDBook(CRUDBase[Book, BookCreate, BookUpdate]):
    def create_with_owner(
        self, db: Session, *, obj_in: BookCreate, owner_id: int
    ) -> Book:
        # check if the publisher exists
        publisher = crud.publisher.show(db=db, name=obj_in.publisher.name)
        if not publisher:
            # create a new publisher
            publisher = crud.publisher.create(
                db=db, obj_in=PublisherCreate(name=obj_in.publisher.name)
            )

        obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in_data)
        db_obj = self.model(
            **obj_in_data,
            owner_id=owner_id,
            publisher_id=publisher.id,
        )
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

That is consumed with the below API method

```
@router.post("/", response_model=schemas.Book)
def create_book(
    *,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    book_in: schemas.BookCreate,
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_user),
) -> Any:
    """
    Create new book.
    """
    book = crud.book.create_with_owner(db=db, obj_in=book_in, owner_id=current_user.id)
    return book
```

with the above, I have my schema as how I wanted that is
Example Value

```
Schema
{
  "title": "Atomic Habits",
  "subtitle": "An Easy & Proven Way to Build Good Habits & Break Bad Ones",
  "narrator": "James Clear",
  "publisher": {
    "name": "Penguin Audio"
  },
  "length": 335,
  "release_date": "2022-12-29",
  "language": "English",
  "rating": 4.8,
  "description": [
    "string"
  ],
  "cover_image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/513Y5o-DYtL._SL500_.jpg"
}
```

But the issue comes when passing data for storage. I face a TypeError `TypeError: 'publisher' is an invalid keyword argument for Book`

I think that the type error might be due to the nested publisher object that I am accepting in my schema and possibly passing to the book.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Seems like i have found some sort of a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144192/insert-a-nested-schema-into-a-database-with-fastapi)

Comment: This seem to return a null object for publisher after it is store to db, though the relationship is set.

Comment: Here is an another bit of context to try and work this out. [Github 2194](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2194)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally named the parameter `publishers` (plural) in your `Book` model. Change it to `publisher` (and also the `back_populates` in `Publisher.books`), and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi with you suggestion i  getting a different error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
`

Comment: Oh, that sounds like you are passing in `publisher` as a `dict`, not an SQLAlchemy model. However, since you are passing in `publisher_id` when creating the `Book`, you shouldn't need to pass the `publisher`, SQLAlchemy should populate it automatically.